# I am a beginner in mongodb so plz tell me why it ain't showing data in the object even the data has been saved

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In this image you can see there is no data in the object
[image]

app.js:

```js
    const express = require("express");
    const app = express();
    const path = require("path");
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/logininfo", { useNewUrlParser: true });
    const port = 8080;
    const HackSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      usernamae: "String",
      password: "String",
    });
    const hack = mongoose.model("hack", HackSchema);
    
    app.get("/", function (req, res) {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/index.html"));
    });
    
    app.post("/", (req, res) => {
      var myData = new hack(req.body);
      myData
        .save()
        .then(() => {
          res.send("Your data has been saved to the database");
        })
        .catch(() => {
          res.status(400).send("data was not saved to the database");
        });
    });
    
    app.listen(port);
    console.log("Server started at http://localhost:" + port);
```

Now in the following picture is my mongo shell
[image]

Comment: Try adding some logging in the app.post route so you can see what exactly was sent, and what the object contained prior to saving.  The misspelled `usernamae` in the schema might also prevent storing that data.

Comment: it still giving me the following empty object after using db.items.find() operation: { "_id" : ObjectId("61b983a2632e70d76b499be8"), "__v" : 0 
} even the data has been saved :( I can't understand why I am not getting any data in the collection

Comment: What does `myData` contain prior to saving?